# Not printing Receiving Channel value on console

Tags: go

I am a learner to GoLang and was trying to experiment and learn about Sync package and chan concept.

Follwoing is the code I am running and expecting to print **Receiving Channel Value** on console, but the value is not getting printed, it print the values sometimes but not always.

If I range through the chan without putting it into the go routine then its printing all the channel values but failing with an error "**fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!**"

I tried synchronizing the channel reading using channel "done", but in that case it again started failing with same error. I also tried waitGroup API as well which you can see in my code (commented), but that also didn't worked for me.

Thanks for the help

**Source Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type safeOperation struct {
    i int
    sync.Mutex
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    so := new(safeOperation)
    ch := make(chan int)
    //done := make(chan bool)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go so.Increment(ch)
        go so.Decrement(ch)
    }

    go func() {
        //wg.Add(1)
        for c := range ch {
            fmt.Println("Receiving Channel Value: ", c)
        }
        //wg.Done()
        //done <- true
    }()
    //wg.Wait()
    //<-done
    fmt.Println("Value: ", so.GetValue())
    fmt.Println("Main method finished")
}

func (so *safeOperation) Increment(ch chan int) {
    //so.Lock()
    //defer wg.Done()
    so.i++
    ch <- so.i
    //so.Unlock()
}

func (so *safeOperation) Decrement(ch chan int) {
    //so.Lock()
    //defer wg.Done()
    so.i--
    ch <- so.i
    //so.Unlock()
}

func (so *safeOperation) GetValue() int {
    so.Lock()
    v := so.i
    so.Unlock()
    return v
}
```

**Output:**
Value:  1
Main method finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good pattern for using `WaitGroup` is to call `Add()` before you send to the channel or use the `go` keyword, and call `Done()` after receiving from the channel.
This way you can be sure that `Add()` is always called on-time, regardless of whether sending on the channel blocks.

I have changed your example code to do this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type safeOperation struct {
    i int
    sync.Mutex
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    so := new(safeOperation)
    ch := make(chan int)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go so.Increment(ch)
        wg.Add(1)
        go so.Decrement(ch)
    }

    go func() {
        for c := range ch {
            fmt.Println("Receiving Channel Value: ", c)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    //<-done
    fmt.Println("Value: ", so.GetValue())
    fmt.Println("Main method finished")
}

func (so *safeOperation) Increment(ch chan int) {
    so.i++
    ch <- so.i
}

func (so *safeOperation) Decrement(ch chan int) {
    so.i--
    ch <- so.i
}

func (so *safeOperation) GetValue() int {
    so.Lock()
    v := so.i
    so.Unlock()
    return v
}
```

[Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/xce_7sFdgqf)

Of course you also want to protect `safeOperation.i` with a mutex (or its value will be unpredictable), but this is all that is necessary to get the desired output.